# How to share a service across multiple applications and check if it already running?

Tags: android, android-service

My problem is that I want to make an SDK (Library project to be included in different app projects) with an IntentService in it. This intent service is scheduled with the AlarmManager to repeat every 2 seconds(in reality this will be every 2 minutes):

```java
Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent("com.my.package.MY_UNIQUE_ACTION");
startServiceIntent.setClass(context, InstalledAppsService.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, startServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 2000, 2000, pendingIntent);
```

So when I use this method from the app which started the service:

```java
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent("com.my.package.MY_UNIQUE_ACTION");
    startServiceIntent.setClass(context, InstalledAppsService.class);
    boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
            startServiceIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);

    return alarmUp;
}
```

it returns true if the service is scheduled. I do not want to have the same service started from different apps with the same SDK. I want one service for all apps with the SDK and I only need to check if this service is running from each app.

But when I use this same method but from a different app it returns false.
This is my manifest:

```xml
<service
    android:name="com.test.services.InstalledAppsService"
    android:exported="true"
    android:process="com.test.InstalledAppsService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.my.package.MY_UNIQUE_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Should I add something to the manifest or use the ActivityManager to check if the process is there? Currently I get two log tags from two different services.

What I want is to: Start service, do the job, dispose service. I don't need it to run always. And currently the alarm manager does that but with separate processes.

This is my service:

```java
public class InstalledAppsService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "services.InstalledAppsService";

    public InstalledAppsService() {
        super("InstalledAppsService");
    }

    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that my service did it's job just too fast and by the time the next app checks if the service is running it had already done it's job and was destroyed from the system. Also the AlarmManager does not have the option to check if anything is scheduled.

So I made a timertask which would do the job and by that way the system didn't destroy the service when it finished it's job.

The service code can be seen here: 
[Here](https://github.com/naughtyspirit/appspice/blob/master/appspice/src/main/java/it/appspice/android/services/InstalledAppsService.java)

And using this method:

```
private boolean isServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)  
    context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I could detect if the service is running.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I add something to the manifest or use the ActivityManager to check if the process is there?

Neither. In particular, there is no guarantee at any point in time that your process exists, so using `ActivityManager` will be ineffective, unless you are going to poll frequently for minutes. And unless the apps are all signed by the same signing key, I'm skeptical that your `android:process` value will work anyway.

At minimum, you need to get rid of `setClass()` in your `isMyServiceRunning()` code, as that limits the `Intent` to the implementation of that class in your app. Without it, it should, in theory, check for a `PendingIntent` wrapped around an `Intent` that is generically for your action string, which would pick up any app's implementation. The `PendingIntent`, when executed by something like `AlarmManager`, will execute some service with that action in its `<intent-filter>`.

I would expect that result to work occasionally and insecurely. I say "occasionally" as it will be interesting to see how you handle reboots, force-stops, and anything else that might unschedule the alarm. I say "insecurely" because any app can implement that action string in a service, and the alarms might run that app instead of one of yours. You might be able to do something with a custom permission to try to at least not launch some spoof service, though custom permissions have their own security issues.

If I were trying to do this, I'd focus on coming up with a more robust election protocol, to designate one app with your service as being the responsible party, until and unless it is uninstalled (at which point, you need a fresh election). Getting this to work well will be somewhat complicated.

You might consider altering your SDK to allow for independently-operating clients, perhaps in part by going with a much lower event frequency than 30 times per hour.